# How to add a css class programmatically to a piece of code?

Tags: php, css, class, drupal

I have this code that just paste the drupal(7) search form whatever I need to.

```
<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_block_form')); ?>
```

The thing is that there´s no way for me to target that particular `input[type="text"]` without modifying other text inputs within the page.

I´ve tried to wrap the code into a class DIV, let´s say *special-search-form*, so I could just do

```
.special-search-form input[type="text"] {}
```

But that won´t do.
Is there a way to add a class inside that drupal_render() call?

Comment: Well, you could modify the view of the `search_block_form`

Comment: have you tried just `.special-search-form input` without the `[type="text]` on the end?

Comment: Yes, and it does nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this.

A) Through a module

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'search_block_form':
      $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'extra_class';
      break;
  }
}
```

I think this might also work too, though I'd need to clarify that ...

```
function hook_search_block_form_alter(...) {
  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'extra_class';
}
```

B) Through a theme *[search-block-form.tpl.php]*

```
<div class="extra_class">
  <?php echo $search_form; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but aren´t those classes affecting all serch forms? Is there a way to target a special one? (I neer a search form at the top and another one at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use form ID as root css class. Something like:

```
#search-block-form input {}
```

Or define it in more detail:

```
#search-block-form input[name="search_block_form"] {}
```